# Android studio java onKeyUp getting called on down, not release

Tags: java, android-studio, onkeydown, onkeyup

I'm trying to code simple wasd controls in android studio. I was trying to use onKeyDown and onKeyUp to move my character while the key is pressed by having onKeyDown set a boolean for my movement to true, and then having onKeyUp set it to false. Right now though when I press and hold a key they both just get called over and over, and nothing happens when I release the key. I know onKeyDown is supposed to behave that way. But why is onKeyUp doing the same thing? Here's an example of my simplified onKeyUp function I'm using for testing:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onKeyUp: keycode=" + keyCode + ", event=" + event);

    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
            Log.d(TAG, "up key a");
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D:
            Log.d(TAG, "up key d");
            break;
        default:
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
    return true;
}
```

How do I catch when the key is actually released?